# Prove that $f$ can be continuously extended over $X$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a normal topological space and $F$ be a non-empty closed subset of $X$. Suppose $f:F\to\mathbb{R^n}$ is a continuous function. Now it is required to prove that $f$ can be continuously extended over $X$. The following is my attempt.

Since $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R^n}$ are homeomorphic let $g:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a homeomorphism. Then $g\circ f:F\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous. Now by Tietze's extension theorem $g\circ f:F\to\mathbb{R}$ can be extended continuously over $X$, call that function $h$. Then we have $g^{-1}\circ h:X\to\mathbb{R^n}$ continuous which is an extension of $f$.

Is my argument alright? Someone please help. Thanks.

**Added later:**
Say $f(x)=(f_1(x),...,f_n(x))$. Then since $f$ is continuous, $f_i:F\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous for $i=1,...,n$. By Tietze's extension theorem extend each $f_i$ continuously over $X$, say the resulting functions are $h_i:X\to\mathbb{R}$. Then $h(x)=(h_1(x),...,h_n(x))$ is a continuous extension of $f$ over $X$.

Comment: The trouble is that there's only such a $g$ if $n=1$. Think of $f$ as an $n$-tuple of maps $f(x)=(f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x))$.

Comment: I have a question about your question: Do you know if it is possible to replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by some (normal?) topological space $(Y,\sigma)$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I added a new solution. Is it alright?

Comment: That's now correct!

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Thank you very much :)

Comment: @user237522 No I'm not sure. What I know is that the product of two normal spaces is not necessarily normal under the product topology. Anyway what's your point? I am curious to know if it is possible.

Comment: @Janitha357, I am just curious to know if your claim can be generalized and how (so I suggested, for example, taking $Y$ to be a normal topological space).

Comment: Along the lines of the proof of Tietze's Extension theorem I think it is not possible. I am not sure though.

Comment: $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R$ are not homeomorphic for $n>1$. For instance, $\mathbb R-\{0\}$ is disconnected, and there is no such "cut point" for $n>1$.